# Is $f(x,y)=xy/(x^{2}+y^{2}) $ differentiable or continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm taking a course in Analysis of several variables and the text we're following is Analysis on Manifolds - Munkres.

I'm having issues to interpret properly the results I'm getting in my exercises. I'm trying the second exercise in Section 5:

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting $f(0)=0$ and

$$f(x,y)=xy/(x^{2}+y^{2}) \quad \textit{if} \quad (x,y) \neq 0.$$

(a) For wich vectors $u \neq 0$ does $f^{\prime}(0;u)$ exist? Evaluate it when it exists.

(b) Do $D_{1}f$ and $D_{2}f$ exist at $0$ ?

(c) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$ ?

(d) Is $f$ continous a $0$?

For the item (a) I take a vector $u=(h,k)$ and from the definition of $f^{\prime}(a;u)$ I get

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f[(0,0)+ (th,tk)]-f(0,0)}{t}= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t}\frac{t^{2}hk}{(th)^{2}+(tk)^{2}}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{hk}{t(h^{2}+k^{2})}$$

After this I don't know how to interpret if it actually exist or no, and don't understand either how or what to evaluate when it exists.

About the item (b) I did this and I don't know if that's correct:

$$D_{1}f(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f[(0,0)+t(1,0)]-f(0,0)}{t} = lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t,0)}{t} = 0$$ And the same with $D_{2}f(0,0) = 0$

Is that correct?

With item (c) tried the same with the definition and I got stuck :

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)-Bh}{|h|} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h_{1},h_{2})-B(h_{1},h_{2})}{|(h_{1},h_{2})|}$$

Once I get here I don't know what to do, should I evaluate $f(h_{1},h_{2})$ ? and if I do, then how can I interprate if it is differentialbe at $0$ ?

Finally for the item (d) I have no clue how to do it, I really need help for this part. I really appreciate if you help me understading completely how can I do it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the first one, note that $\lim \limits_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{hk}{t(h^{2}+k^{2})}\right)=\frac{hk}{h^2+k^2}\lim \limits_{t\to 0}\left(\frac 1 t\right)$. What conditions can you impose on $(h,k)$ to force this limit to exist? The second one is correct. For the third one either ignore it and prove that $f$ isn't continuous at the origin or recall that $B$ must be the null map and then consider the limit along the paths $t\mapsto (t,kt)$ with $k\in \mathbb R$ (might be useful to consider $k>-1$, but this is just a small detail). The fourth one is surely a duplicate, consider $t\mapsto (t,kt)$.

Comment: @GitGud The only thing I can think about (h,k) is that I can take $u=(0,k) $ or $u=(h,0)$ I'm correct about it? If no, then I don't know the answer. Also, can you help me a little more about the differentiation please, I'm kind of lost with this one.

Comment: The limit exists if, and only if, $hk=0$.Regarding differentiation, $f$is differentiableat the origin if, and only if, $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)-Bh}{|h|}=0$. This is so by definition. But this limit doesn't even exist as you can check with the sublimits I mentioned.